# Can I use Vue + Vuetify in legacy project that needs to support IE?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, vuetify.js

Currently adding some functionality to a legacy project. The front end is just jquery for all the webpages. I've been told to add another webpage and really want to use Vuetify + Vue due to the complex functionality requested... There is no webpack or any of the nice features we have today which is a bit of a setback for me, but I'll just use a CDN.

The problem I'm having is needing to support IE (user requested). Currently these script tags make everything work in Chrome:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-resource@1.5.1"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
<script  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<jsp:include page="components/location_component.jsp"></jsp:include>
```

How do I get this to work in IE with just using CDN? I'm running into errors regarding ES6 syntax, which is why I have brought in babel. Still getting the same errors as before.

```
    <div id="app">
        <v-app> 
            <v-container> 
                <location @workstationchange="handleWorkstationChange($event)"></location> 

            </v-container> 
        </v-app>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el : '#app',
        data : {
            workstationSelected : null,
        },
        methods : {
            handleWorkstationChange : function(id) {
                this.workstationSelected = id
            }
        },
        mounted: function(){

        }
    })
</script>
```

Location is a pretty lengthy component I have created, but it's just got some drop down menus that populate from a database... Nothing too complex. It uses ES6 arrow functions, sorting, Set(), spread operator [...] etc... Trying to keep this post somewhat short.

Anyone know how to get ES6 working in a Legacy environment compatible with IE by only using CDN? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: To use babel you need some kind of build process that converts ES6 code to ES5 (or older, you didn’t specify the IE version).

Comment: IE 11 is the version. I don't know much about babel so can you elaborate on this build process?

Comment: The Babel setup page has a lot of examples for different build processes. For example, you could use webpack or you can setup WebStorm to compile ES6 to ES5. https://babeljs.io/setup

Comment: Ok I can't use webpack because this is a legacy project. My job doesn't allow me to use WebStorm either. They only allow Eclipse so both of those options are off the table. I literally just have a JSP file with Vue + Vuetify + Babel scripts. When I use the standalone babel cdn and add `<script type="text/babel">` it throws an exception in a file called lang.ts which is derived from the Vuetify CDN. The error is on this line of code `const fallback = Symbol('Lang fallback')` and says 'Symbol' is undefined. This only happens in internet explorer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise you could load `Babel` at runtime! Learned something new :).It's correct that IE does not support Symbol, you can see that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol.  I don't think Babel will transpile all the Vue CDN code! So that's where your problem lies.

Comment: Hey I appreciate it man I guess it's back to raw javascript for me!

Comment: I use Vuetify + Vue in a legacy project which also does not use Webpack or any build process. What I have done is built the Vue + Vuetify project outside of the legacy project and used Webpack with Babel to build it. Then in my legacy project I import the build.js which is IE11 friendly.

Comment: @DoritoBandito I think this will solve my issue. If you want to submit this as an answer to the question go ahead I'll give you the green check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Vuetify with support for IE11.

To use it in a legacy project which can not take advantage of build tools such as Webpack, you can build your project outside of your legacy project and then use a build tool such as Webpack to build the project. You can then import the Javascript file Webpack outputs, typically /dist/build.js into your legacy project like this for example:

```
<script src="build.js" />
```

You will also need to bring over any assets you're using in your Vue project to the legacy project.

Although unconventional, it does work and can also take advantage of existing Javascript and web services in your project as if it was there to begin with.

Comment: Thanks a lot this was a very creative approach